# Including "Force "option to onclick "install" button for a particular package

Tags: linux, lua, package, openwrt, luci

Is it possible to include --force-overwrite option inside the on-click of "install" button for any particular package in the openwrt lua web page??

Comment: Could You please be more specific with Your setup? OpenWrt version, server being run, etc. Because, as I see, it's already being forced on current    [openwrt/luci](https://github.com/openwrt/luci) master branch.

Source: [web admin interface controller](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/blob/622cfc673ab2e97001ed394f8cd6d0425d8f3378/modules/luci-mod-admin-full/luasrc/controller/admin/system.lua#L88-L104) , [relevant flags on ipkg library](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/blob/84346cd178ca0740817edc6f81d8f90e7bc6e00c/modules/luci-base/luasrc/model/ipkg.lua#L15) .

Comment: @ Kamiccolo : Thanks I got it done by using --force options in package files

Comment: could You please share Your solution in the answer section? :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just included --force-overwrite (subcommand options) inside the return install () function for particular lua scripts